# What's the recommended way to fix column width wrapping for SO's documentation?

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation

When tables are used to present information in SO's documentation, the content in one column gets wrapped unexpected due to the content width of the column next to it.

Here's one concrete example of this happening: [Lua's Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/lua/659/getting-started-with-lua#t=201702010405373067839&a=remarks), in the version section the first and third columns are getting wrapped due to the long sentences present in the 'Notes' column.

So far the only way I've found to handle this is to insert `<br>` breaks every so often in the excessively long columns. None of the other markdowns or tags seem to achieve the desired formatting.

Is there a better way to handle this issue?

Comment: Layout hints for the columns like minimal/maximal/preferred-widths in pixel or percent or stretch factors maybe?

Comment: Can we use inline styles? Because you could try wrapping each version value in `<div style="white-space: nowrap"></div>`. Kind of a pain though.

Comment: Instead of putting the notes in the column, add them at the bottom in a numbered list.  Then reference these notes in the column by number.  Tada!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan How do I position this tag exactly? I tried within each column, only on single excessive column, even enclosing the entire table but it doesn't have any effect. Note it uses the `|` and `---` markdown symbols to create this table (also using Ctrl-E).

Comment: @Will I suppose that's one possibility here but there could be cases where turning the menacingly long column into 'footnotes' isn't always appropriate.

Comment: Use flexbox, not table.

Comment: @Trilarion yea I like this approach, pretty flexible. I'll try this first. Gotta look out for edge cases though.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I believe these `<table>`s are generated in markdown, so not sure about inline styles. Could try `white-space: nowrap` on.. `<th>`'s.. maybe? Tricky case we want _some_ things to wrap.

Comment: Well, like I said, we'd put the style on a div wrapping the content we wanted to not wrap. However, I just tried it, and it looks like it ignores HTML markup within the table cells once you add inline styles. I just wasn't sure if it'd work. I even tried the ancient `nobr` tag, but that didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I ended up applying `white-space: nowrap` to the `<th>`'s.

In spot checking a number of popular topics, I found few instances of 8 column `<table>`s. A `min-width` on table `<td>`'s or `<th>`'s made these tables wider than their container, even though there was room to spare in the cells.

However, I didn't find any instances of large, multi-column tables with long `<th>`'s. Forcing `<th>`'s onto one line didn't make any tables I tested too wide. Obviously this is not a bulletproof fix, so if anyone sees a wide table that breaks its container, please let us know here or elsewhere on Meta.

Thanks again for reporting!